# How to comment on somebody's clothes?

Tags: usage, politeness

Is it correct to say e.g. "I like your way of wearing" or "the way you wear looks perfect"?

Is it politely? Is it in use or not? May I use "the way you wear" referring to whole wearings including dress, scarf, hat, bracelet. jewellery, etc?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about etiquette or social conventions and doesn't seem to be about language. The question could be made appropriate for this site if it were asked about what the meanings of particular given ways of attempting to being polite are
.

Comment: This is English Learner - it's totally about language. It's about subtle meanings of a word or sentence that you can't find in a dictionary, but that are essential to get along with the natives.

Comment: You should say: _Nice threads!_ or _fire vines._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To refer to someone's whole ensemble, or even their overall style of dress you can say,

> I like/admire the way you dress.

or

> I like/admire your style.

Answer (score 4):

Some normal things to say would be:

> I like your outfit/dress/etc.
>
> You look really nice today.
>
> You wear that scarf/etc really well.

Normally it's fine to compliment your friends on their clothes, but it can be kind of weird with strangers.

Comment: Tanx. I consider the type of relationship in compliment, but I wanted to know that wether is correct to use "the way you wear" as a concept for whole clothing or not? (Any kind of wearings including dress, scarf, hat, bracelet. jewellery, etc.)

Comment: Unless it is spoken by a guy as a pick-up line.

Comment: @user14044- Just curious- Why do you use *Tanx*? the word is *thanks* and isn't even pronounced like *Tanx* and if you are using some sort of abbreviated texting-style shorthand it's typically *ty* (**t**hank **y**ou)  OF course I don't suggest you use *ty* on this site.

Comment: I know, but it's kind of text messaging style I think. But why do you suggest not to use ty?

Comment: In my opinion, this site is devoted to the English language.  I think the level of formality for this site should be higher than that of casual text messaging.  This site is supposed to be a resource for future users and we should try to make it the best one we can.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't use the word "wearing", but "dressing". "I like your way of dressing" (more likely "I like the way you dress"), "the way you dress looks perfect".

It's a bit strong. Maybe if you meet a friend at the opera in a very nice suit or in an evening dress, then it would be appropriate. Saying it to a well-dressed colleague might raise an eyebrow.

Answer (score 0):

I have not heard "wearings" used this way.

If you said:

> I like the way you **wear** your dress.

it is more about the clothing itself, how it fits on her, or how it is arranged with other clothing. But in this sense you are only complimenting the clothes.

If you are complementing the person on how she looks (which includes clothing), it is better to use the verb *look*.

> I (really) **like** the way you look today.

which is understood to include clothing. Using *really* would make it more personal.

On the other hand, you could make it passive if you need to be more formal:

> You **are looking** nice today.

And if you are referring to all clothing items, including jewelry and accessories, you could use "outfit":

> I really like your **outfit**.

Comment: Thank you, but i think i couldn't clear my point. Imagine a metal guy/girl with all those braclets, chains! or other metal stuff. How do you say something about the whole gear and somehow the whole package? I appreciate your answer.

Comment: You could use "outfit" in place of clothing, which would include jewelry and accessories. "I really like your *outfit*."

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem is that wear requires an object. So the following are ungrammatical:

> *You are wearing.
>
> *I like the way you wear.
>
> *I like your wearing.

They need to have objects to be grammatical:

> You are wearing **shoes.**
>
> I like the way you wear your **pants.**
>
> I like **what** you are wearing.

Comment: Good point. I think the best suggestions are 1.I like the way you dress and 2.I really like your outfit.

Answer (score 0):

It's not too common, but the phrase *becomes you* might be of interest.

According to [YD](http://www.yourdictionary.com/become), it means:

> **become** (*v. trans.*) to look good with: *The new suit becomes you*.

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/become) lists it this way, under Definintion 3:

> **become** (*v. trans.*) (of clothes, etc) to enhance the appearance of (someone); suit ⇒ *that dress becomes you*

It's a flexible verb, in that you could use it for a single piece of jewelry or an entire ensemble.